# If the set of vectors $U$ is linearly independent in a subspace $X$, then can vectors be removed from $U$ to create a basis for $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I believe the answer is False, but only based on an intuitive feeling right now as I cannot manage to definitively prove why, ie, I've been trying to find a counterexample but can't. Also, does the fact that $U$ is a "subspace" rather than a vector-space change anything? (I don't think it does).

My current reasoning is:
By the definition of a basis, we should only consider spanning sets. But if it were also linearly independent, then the set would need to be minimally spanning, thus we cannot remove any vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.

If $\operatorname{span}(U)\subsetneq X$  then any set $V$ resulting from removing vectors from $U$ will verify that $\operatorname{span}(V)\subset\operatorname{span}(U)\subsetneq X$ and thus $\operatorname{span}(V)\neq X$.

If $\operatorname{span}(U)= X$ then $U$ is a basis.

Comment: not true as in you cannot remove vectors?

Comment: You can remove vectors but the resulting set will generate a smaller space. If originally $U$ didn't span the whole space, it is impossible for the new set to span it and thus be a base.

Answer (score 2):

If $U$ spans $X$ then $U$ is a basis already. If $U$ does not span $X$ then you won't get a basis by removing any vectors.

Counterexample: $ U = \{e_1\}$ and $X = \mathbb{R}^2$.